# How to pass parameters from input control at Studio to Java bean collection data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to do a small POC on Jasper reports. I am trying to explore the functionality on Java Bean collection data sources.

In my POC, I would collect some data input from the user. Based on the input, a query must be triggered on a SQL DB and the results must be used to populate the report.

Here are the brief steps that I followed to get this done.

1. Created an empty jasper project.
2. Created the `Employee` class which will represent the data to be displayed on the report.

```
public class Employee {
    private String name = "";
    private Double salary = 0.0D;
    private String description = "";

    public Employee(String name, Double salary, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

3. Created the `EmployeeFactory` class which is responsible to query the DB and fetch data and populate the `Employee` object.

```
public class EmployeeFactory {

    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jasper";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "root";
    static final String QUERY = "SELECT name,salary FROM Employees";

    public static Collection<Employee> getCollection() {
        List<Employee> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try(
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    DB_URL,
                    USER,
                    PASS
            )
        ){

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(QUERY);

            while( resultSet.next() ) {
                Employee employee = new Employee(
                        resultSet.getString("name"),
                        resultSet.getDouble("salary"),
                        ""
                );
                result.add(employee);
            }

        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        return result;
    }

    
}
```

4. Made a jar out of the above Java project and added it to the classpath of the jasper project.
5. Created a data adapter of type `Collection of JavaBeans`. Here, in the wizard, I specified the factory class responsible to create the data beans(`EmployeeFatory`) and also the static method responsible for it(`public static Collection<Employee> getCollection()`)

I am able to get the report until this point working.

Additionally, I want to execute filtering on the SQL seen in `EmployeeFactory`; say `select * from employees e where salary > 1000`

I want to give a functionality to pass the report parameter `1000` from the input control onto the Java Bean data source. Is there any way we can pass parameters from the input control at Jaspersoft Studio to the Java Bean data source?

Comment: `Is there any way we can pass parameters from the input control to the Java Bean data source?` - Is this question about using JasperReports Server?

Comment: @AlexK This is about Jasper Studio.

Comment: Any input control is bind to the parameter. Your question is unclear

Comment: @AlexK yes, there is an input control which is taking the salary amount as input. I am trying to get the SQL query to filter based on the input control